# How to search for text within in a solution while excluding certain projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

How do I find text in my Visual Studio solution while *excluding* certain projects? Preferably a macro within the text editor window itself and/or a setting somewhere.

**Example**: I want to find every instance of the text "barcode" in my solution but I want to exclude looking at the "LotsOfBarcodes" project because I already know that text string exists there a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is acceptable to you, but one option is to temporarily unload the project(s) that you don't want to search from your solution. Follow that with a `Look in: Entire Solution` option in the `Find and Replace` dialog box. Reload the projects when you are done.

Comment: Thank you, though I'd call this more of a creative work around. I was hoping for some sort of text modifier or something I can put in the text query.

Comment: I wish there was a better way too.